# Java enum reverse lookup

Tags: java, enums

So I have this enum that doesn't work as I expected and need some modifications:

```
public enum MyEnum {

    CODE000("text description comes here"),

    private final String value;

    private static final Map<String, MyEnum> LOOKUP = Maps.uniqueIndex(
            Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()),
            MyEnum::getValue
    );

    MyEnum(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;

    }


    public static MyEnum fromStatus(String status) {
        return LOOKUP.get(status);
    }
}
```

The way it works now is:

`MyEnum.fromStatus("text description comes here")` and of course I want the other way around:

`MyEnum.fromStatus("CODE000")` to return me `"text description comes here"`

Can someone suggest how I can change this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is a literal lookup, which you get by calling `valueOf`:

```
MyEnum code000 =  MyEnum.valueOf("CODE000");
```

And then:

```
String val = code000.getValue();
```

Please note that an exception will be raised if the string passed to `valueOf` doesn't resolve to an enum literal in `MyEnum`.

Comment: What if text desc is different than enum literal like "Code of 000"

Comment: @AmitBera If that's anticipated, an exception should be expected. Otherwise, a separate "lookup" method can be added to iterate over `values()` and compare the `value` field. But the example in the question seems simple enough to just rely on `valueOf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your key function (`MyEnum::getValue`) is wrong as it returns the value. 
It must be `MyEnum::name`

This will return the enum and not the text description as the value of the map is of type `MyEnum`. You can get the text value by calling `getValue` on the enum OR you can store the value in the map instead of the enum

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get an enum value by enum name you can use this function :

```
public static String fromStatus(String status) {
    MyEnum myEnum = valueOf(status);

    return myEnum.getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers so far are using the method `valueOf`. This method will return the enum constant as long as you provide a name of an enum constant. Otherwise an `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown.

In your question you're using a lookup map. The Map (it looks like as it's created by Guava `Maps`) will return for non-enum-constant-names `null`. It will not throw a `IllegalArgumentException` in such cases. So it is a different behaviour.

In addition you say: *"and of course I want the other way around"*
This means you want to get the enum by status and the status by an enums name.

Therefore you would need to have two lookup methods:

- status -> enum
- name -> status

But you would get a compile time error if you define the two methods you mentioned:

```
  public static MyEnum fromStatus(String status) { ... }

  public static String fromStatus(String name) { ... }
```

The compiler could not distinguish the methods by name and parameter. But even though you wrote `MyEnum.fromStatus("CODE000")` actually it's the enum constant name you are using as parameter. So let's resolve the naming conflict by calling the second method `fromName`. The code for `MyEnum` could look like this:

```
public enum MyEnum {

  CODE000("text description comes here");

  private final String value;

  private static final Map<String, MyEnum> LOOKUP_ENUM = Maps.uniqueIndex(Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()), MyEnum::getValue);
  private static final Map<String, String> LOOKUP_STATUS = Arrays.stream(MyEnum.values()).collect(Collectors.toMap(MyEnum::name, MyEnum::getValue));

  MyEnum(final String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public String getValue() {
    return value;

  }

  public static MyEnum fromStatus(String status) {
    return LOOKUP_ENUM.get(status);
  }

  public static String fromName(String name) {
    return LOOKUP_STATUS.get(name);
  }

}
```

If you want to lookup the enum constants by it's names in the same manner (no exception on non-enum-constant-names), you need a third map and a third lookup method:

```
  private static final Map<String, MyEnum> LOOKUP = Maps.uniqueIndex(Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values()), MyEnum::name);

  public static MyEnum byName(String name) {
    return LOOKUP.get(name);
  }
```

This would work as follows:

```
System.out.println(MyEnum.fromStatus("text description comes here")); // CODE000
System.out.println(MyEnum.fromStatus("invalid")); // null - no exception
System.out.println(MyEnum.fromStatus(null)); // null - no exception

System.out.println(MyEnum.fromName("CODE000")); // "text description comes here"
System.out.println(MyEnum.fromName("invalid")); // null - no exception
System.out.println(MyEnum.fromName(null)); // null - no exception

System.out.println(MyEnum.byName("CODE000")); // CODE000
System.out.println(MyEnum.byName("invalid")); // null - no exception
System.out.println(MyEnum.byName(null)); // null - no exception
```

If you need the `byName` method I would suggest to rename the method`fromName` to something like `statusByName` to keep them comprehensible apart.

Finally one more suggestion:
Since the lookup methods may return `null` we could return `Optional<String>` / `Optional<MyEnum>` as result. This would allow to immediately continue processing the result.

```
  public static Optional<MyEnum> fromStatus(String status) { ... }
  public static Optional<String> statusByName(String name) { ... }
  public static Optional<MyEnum> byName(String name) { ... }
```